# Joomla 3 - Pagination limit

Tags: joomla-3.x, pagination

I am trying to override the standard Joomla pagination. Instead of showing 10 links then the next / end links, I would like to show 20 links up front.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What component are you actually paginating? com_content?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, because it is a core hack and not recommended. Maybe someone can fill in on how to make a proper override.

In the file `ROOT\libraries\cms\pagination\pagination.php`, look for `$displayedPages = 10;` (about line #130), and change it to `$displayedPages = 20;`.

As this is a core hack, it will be overridden whenever you update Joomla, and you'll have to apply it again.